# Finding the correct application path for IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have created a HelloWorld WEbService and wanted to define it for IIS.
So I right clicked on IIS and said Create New Application which gave me the dialog below. But what is the correct path I should point it to? I tried bin folder and the main WebSerivce folder I had and both failed in Test Connection

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've always done it is to right-click on `Default Web Site`, select `Add Virtual Directory`. Once you successfully add the correct directory, you can then right-click on it and select something like `Convert to Application`. And your going to want to point it to wherever your `default.aspx` or `index.html` or its equivalent is.